# How to sort an array based on the values of another (partial) array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

How to sort an array based on the values of another (partial) array in PHP? I.e. `$toBeSorted` is the target array, `$sortByThis` provides the keys (not all keys!):

```php
// Array to be sorted (mantaining key-values correlations)
$toBeSorted = array(
    'id'       => 'Identifier',
    'username' => 'Username',
    'phone'    => 'Phone number',
    'email'    => 'E-mail',
);

$sortByThis = array('username', 'id');

// Result should be username, id, email, phone
// The remaining portion of array should be sorted with ksort()
```

I remember (but I'm not 100% sure) a function to quickly do this. Actually I've used:

```php
// Sort the first portion of the array
$sorted = array_intersect_key($toBeSorted, array_flip($sortByThis));

// Sort the remaining portion
$remain = array_diff_key($toBeSorted, $sorted);
ksort($remain);

$toBeSorted = array_merge($sorted, $remain);
```

Comment: I imagine you'll have to code something yourself. What have you attempted so far?

Comment: array_intersect + ksort. I remember a function to quickly do this, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)** to put together.

```
uksort($toBeSorted, function($a, $b) use ($sortByThis) {
    $key_a = array_search($a, $sortByThis);
    $key_b = array_search($b, $sortByThis);
    if ($key_a === false && $key_b === false) {
        return strcmp($a, $b);
    } else if ($key_a === false) {
        return 1;
    } else if ($key_b === false) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return $key_a - $key_b;
    }
});
```

**[THE DEMO.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/c3b6eu)**

Comment: Hint: assign results of `array_search` to variables for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Simply using `array_merge` seems to work:

```
ksort($toBeSorted);
print_r(array_merge(array_flip($sortByThis), $toBeSorted));
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [username] => Username
    [id] => Identifier
    [email] => E-mail
    [phone] => Phone number
)
```

Link to [codepad](http://codepad.org/HQwG7dba)

Comment: `phone` and `email` have to be sorted ASC.

Comment: @hsz didn't read that, but it's enough to add a ksort(). Is [this](http://codepad.org/HQwG7dba) what you mean?

Comment: `ksort` before merge does the job. Edit your answer please.

Answer (score 0):

have a look on array_multisort() function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

You can achieve this by doing something like this.

```
$sorted_arr= array_multisort($toBeSorted, array('username'=>SORT_ASC, 'id'=>SORT_ASC));
```

If this not help you there are other functions submitted by users.